# Grid of modal Images

Tags: javascript, html

I created a grid of images and I want to open a popup of the zoomed clicked image, a modal image. I tried to save the id of the clicked image in sessionStorage and get it back but it doesn't seem to be the right way to do it.

```html
<!-- The Modal -->

        <div id="myModal2" class="modal">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <img class="modal-content" id="img02">
            <div id="caption"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="img">
            <a1 href="Img/7.png">
                <figure>
                    <img id="myImg" src="Img/7.png" alt="" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">
                </figure>
            </a1>

            <a1 href="Img/7.png">
                <figure>
                    <img id="myImg2" src="Img/7.png" alt="" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">
                </figure>
            </a1>

            </a1>
        </div>

        <script>
            function reply_click(clicked_id)
            {
            // Store
            sessionStorage.setItem("ID", clicked_id);
            }

            // Get the modal
            
            var modal = document.getElementById('myModal2');

            // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
            var img = document.getElementById(sessionStorage.getItem("ID"));
            var modalImg = document.getElementById("img" + imgIdNumber);
            var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
            img.onclick = function(){
                modal.style.display = "block";
                modalImg.src = this.src;
                captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
            }

            // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
            var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

            // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
            span.onclick = function() { 
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is done this way:

- learn how to use event [delegation with event target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).
- in your `onClick="reply_click(event)"` pass event
- define that event an function: `function reply_click(event) {`
- then inside you use `event.target.src` of clicked image and update your modal `src`, and so on. `event.target` is your clicked element and you can get all info about it.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal2')
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img02");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

function reply_click(event) {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = event.target.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = event.target.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img02">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<div class="img">
  <a1 href="Img/7.png">
    <figure>
      <img id="myImg" src="https://dl1.cbsistatic.com/i/2020/05/04/18018b2a-91b1-40b5-b91a-4412a10fac7f/aedc25fa28604a2a87d3b7df56cb4877/imgingest-9025120176881342416.png" alt="" onClick="reply_click(event)">
    </figure>
  </a1>

  <a1 href="Img/7.png">
    <figure>
      <img id="myImg2" src="https://avatarfiles.alphacoders.com/233/thumb-1920-233629.jpg" alt="" onClick="reply_click(event)">
    </figure>
  </a1>

  </a1>
</div>
```